# Dynamic Routing and Component creation based on route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to have a couple of "overview" pages for sections my app, that will all be triggered on the root of that section.

so `localhost/hi` should display component `HiOverview`

`localhost/he` should display component `HeOverview`

as there are multiple of those, i want to avoid assigning the component to a const, then reusing it in a route. instead i want to handle all that in a single dynamic route.

BUT i'm struggling with the creation of the Components in the beforeEnter hook.
each `route` object expects a component... but i just want to decide the component depending on route. (`sectionsWithOverview` is a simple array of strings containing the `name`s of routes where i want an overview displayed

```
const router = new Router({
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/:section',
      component: Placeholder,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const section = to.params.section

      // how can i use this in the next() call?   
      // const View = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'sectionView' */ `Components/${section}/${section}Overview`)

      if (sectionsWithOverview.includes(to.params.section)) {
        next({ name: `${to.params.section}Overview` })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    },
}
```

can you guys help me? how can i conditionally assign a component onBeforeEnter, and then route to that exact Component?
it works if i declare each `SectionOverview` beforehand, but that makes my whole idea pointless.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar with a project but instead I used `beforeRouteUpdate`

Here is an example of how it works. On route.js simply define your dynamic route

```
const router = new Router({
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { 
      path: '/:section',
      component: Placeholder,
      name: 'placeholder'
    },
}
```

Then in your component (I assume Placeholder.vue) in your HTML add this line of code

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <component :is="section" key="section"></component>
</transition>
```

then in your JS add the `beforeRouteUpdate` hook and define all your components that will match your route section param.

```
import he from './heOverview.vue'
import hi from './hiOverview.vue'

beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  // just use `this`
  this.section = to.params.section
  next()
},
components: {
  he,
  hi
},
data () {
  return {
    section: ''
  }
}
```

So when a user navigate to `localhost/he` the `heOverview.vue` component will be loaded. The only thing you have to make sure is that the `section` param's value should match an specific view if not an error will be produced

If you need more info about how this work, read
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Comment: hmmm interesting approach, thanks! but in the end, this means i'll just "import all the components one after another"somewhere else. so i could basically just as well write a route for each one, which i wanted to avoid in the first place :D (right?)

Comment: Yeah, components must be imported somewhere for use, with the example above the router web hook will handle witch component should be used depending on the section param also as you said you can define a route for each component

Comment: do you know of a possibility to get rid of those imports? like... "auto-import the component based on route"? do you think that would be possible?

Comment: Well the documentation doesn't show a way to manage this situation. They always export/import on vue modules. But if your component will be used in many views you can globally import it (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)